# How can I add this lengthy command as alias on git?

Tags: git

I sometimes use this command on git.

```
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "wrong@address.local" ];
    then
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="myname";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="right@address.com";
            git commit-tree "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

I want to add that as alias.
And then I tried as below, it doesn't work...

```
git config --global alias.rewritelog '!f(){ \
    git filter-branch --commit-filter \' \
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "wrong@address.local" ]; \
    then \
        GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="myname"; \
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="right@address.com"; \
        git commit-tree "$@"; \
    else \
        git commit-tree "$@"; \
    fi\' HEAD \
};f'
```

After this command, error occurred.

```
zsh: parse error near `then'
```

Comment: Why not just use a shell alias?

Comment: That is one of solution.
But I always use something command by alias straight straightforward.
And I'm asking how to manage it by git alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot escape single-quotes within single-quotes.
Luckily you can escape double-quotes within double-quotes.
Surround with double-quotes instead of single-quotes:

```
git config --global alias.rewritelog "!f(){ \
    git filter-branch --commit-filter ' \
    if [ \"$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL\" = wrong@address.local ]; \
    then \
        GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=myname; \
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=right@address.com; \
    fi; \
    git commit-tree \"$@\"' HEAD; };f"
```

I also simplified your original code and removed some unnecessary double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks!!
However, different error occurrd.
```zsh: event not found: f(){```

Comment: @Harry try with escaping `!`, so at the beginning write like `\!f(){`